# Unable to mount WebDAV share from terminal

Tags: webdav

I have a server running a WebDAV server. Using nautilus on the GUI of my ubuntu I can connect and read/write files.
I have tried on terminal with the following command:

```
sudo mount -t davfs http://<host>:<port>/<sharename>/ <destination>
```

And the result is:

```
/sbin/mount.davfs: mounting failed; the server does not support WebDAV
```

Is there another way to connect?

Comment: I cannot edit the question, but found another information. The problem is that I have a index.html file on the folder. When I remove it all works fine.

Comment: If removing that file solves your problem post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: This is not a solution, is a workaround. I need this file. And nautilus is able to mount the filesystem with or without the file, so seems like there is another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue recently. Rather than point to a non-existent file, you can just disable the DirectoryIndex :

`DirectoryIndex disabled`

Documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#DirectoryIndex

Source: http://dimitar.me/upgrading-to-apache-2-4-will-prevent-webdav-listing-of-directories-containing-index-files/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why this happen, but I found a workaround. I noticed that the server has a index.html file on the root folder. Removing this file make it work as expected. To be able to get this working without removing the needed file, I changed the DirectoryIndex on virtualhost config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ...

        DirectoryIndex inexistentfile
        ...

</VirtualHost>
```